# how to determine by window handle if it is a popup c#

Tags: c#, winapi

Iterating any window open and having top z order on environment, how can I verify window is not any pop up(tool tip pop up, combo pop up, etc )?

using WinApi method:

```
HWND WINAPI GetWindow(
  _In_ HWND hWnd,
  _In_ UINT uCmd
);


for (IntPtr childWindow = WinAPI.GetWindow(WinAPI.GetDesktopWindow(), WinAPI.GetWindow_Cmd.GW_CHILD);
                childWindow != IntPtr.Zero;
                childWindow = WinAPI.GetWindow(childWindow, WinAPI.GetWindow_Cmd.GW_HWNDNEXT))
{
     //todo if
}
```

Comment: the variety of window managers and libraries on windows and the applications that run on it makes this impossible to tell from any window class property. first example that comes to my mind: a `<div>` constituting a jQuery autocomplete dropdown in a browser process.

Comment: You are going to have to look at the window styles.  Get the Spy++ tool and look at the windows you are interested in.  Then find the appropriate Win32/User32 call to pick out the right bits, then play with P/Invoke (see http://pinvoke.net for that)

Comment: @user3405987 I wrote an entire library of methods which deal with Windows Desktop application automation, most of it was done using this `UIAutomationClient.dll` and `WindowsBase.dll`, you can grab all the open windows as top layer `AutomationElements` of the desktop and then inspect Name, ID and many other attributes using those two .dll files

Comment: The correct way to enumerate top level windows is to use `EnumWindows()`, not a `GetWindow()` loop

Comment: Since, it's `C#`, using `UIAutomation Framework` is easier to perform this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all those who comment, You lead me to solution. Here is a method i test it with Spy++.

please if you have tips/ideas, i will appreciate.

```
    public const long WS_POPUP = 0x80000000L;
    public static bool IsWindowPopup(IntPtr hHandle)
    {
        long style = WinAPI.GetWindowLongPtr(hHandle, -16);
        bool isPopup = ((style & WS_POPUP) != 0);
        return isPopup;
    }
```